# tracing a memory leak with Instruments in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am having problem finding a memory leak with Instruments. Usually it helps me a lot and I am able to find the leak, but in this case I'm lost.

I am creating a view controller that controls a views loaded from NIB file. The view has Map View with "Show user location" on true. Once user location is found I use MKReverseGeocoder to get the location data. The leak is always present when I load this view controller and MapKit finds user location. I figured out that MKReverseGeocoder isn't problem here, since I get the same leak with or without the MKReverseGeocoder.

When I load this view Instruments "leaks" report a memory leak. See the screenshot on the image:
[image]

This is how I initialize my controller:

```
AddPlaceViewController *addPlaceVC = [[AddPlaceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddPlaceViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
addPlaceVC.delegate = self;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addPlaceVC];
self.placeController = navigationController;
[self presentModalViewController:self.placeController animated:YES];
[addPlaceVC release];
[navigationController release];
```

This is all on the iPhone Simulator 4 and targeted OS 3.2.

Is this actually leak or what I am facing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the responsible library is "Foundation" and not your code, there is nothing you can do about it (except report it to Apple).

Comment: IS this true? I've had similar issues when using Instruments reports leaks in Apple APIs. I always tend to think that I'm misinterpreting or reading the report wrong because why would Apple release leaky code? ;) But seriously, is it common that Apple APIs leak or cause leaks?

Comment: There are two possibilities: (1) Apple indeed writes leaky code; (2) Instruments reports false positives. We can't do anything about either.